# Hide meta data from Order Items on Admin Order Page (WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using some custom Item Meta for products sold on my WooCommerce store.  I am looking for a way to hide the item meta from showing up on the Admin Order page, under the order items section.

I am using underscores for the meta name, however the meta is still showing up.

You can see in the attached image what I mean...

Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Hope you can provide more information such as your current wordpress and woocomerce version.

Comment: Thanks Christian,  I am using WordPress 4.2.1 and WooCommerce 2.3.8.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function custom_woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta($arr) {
    $arr[] = '_xchange_code';
    return $arr;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta', 'custom_woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks Christian,  That worked.  But out of curiosity - aren't meta names starting with underscores supposed to be hidden be default?

Comment: Yes, I see woocomerce don't support this feature.

Comment: Meta keys that begin with an underscore are hidden from the custom fields meta box by default, which is not the same thing as what WooCommerce has here.

Comment: I don't understand. I've added a meta_key starting with and underscore, and it still shows within the Admin ... am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

```
//remove order item meta key
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data', 'mobilefolk_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data', 10, 1 );

function mobilefolk_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data($formatted_meta){
    $temp_metas = [];
    foreach($formatted_meta as $key => $meta) {
        if ( isset( $meta->key ) && ! in_array( $meta->key, [
                'lyric_id',
                'lyric_song_title',
                'lyric_artist_name'
            ] ) ) {
            $temp_metas[ $key ] = $meta;
        }
    }
    return $temp_metas;
}
```